# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'books.json'

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django I get an error file not found when trying to read a json file that is in the same directory as views.py

```
# Load books from JSON file
with open('/books.json') as file:
    books = json.load(file)


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'books/index.html', books)
```

Comment: Since the path to the file starts with a `/` you try to open the file in the root directory of the file system.

Comment: So how should it be

Comment: remove '/', in open() to access the file in the same directory as '/' takes you to the sub-directory

Answer (score 2):

if your file is `books.json` you should use "./books.json"